# Datetype conversion error when trying to download 'image' column contents from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to download all of the files/documents stored in a database table. The table's structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[eAttachment](
    [eKey] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [eSize] [int] NULL,
    [eContents] [image] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ePKU_eAttachment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [eKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Typical contents:

```
esize: 173586
ekey: 0 0000000000000000000000000005010 Filename.pdf
econtents: 0x7B00350030000037003500460030002D003400310046....etc
```

The SQL I'm trying to use is failing on line 30 (marked with comment below) with the error below.

> (5 row(s) affected)
>
> (5 row(s) affected)
>
> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 30
>
> Error  converting data type varchar to bigint.

Here is the full code

```
DECLARE @outPutPath varchar(100)
, @i bigint
, @init int
, @econtents varbinary(max) 
, @fPath varchar(max)  
, @folderPath  varchar(max) 
, @efolderName nvarchar(31)
, @ekey nvarchar(250)

DECLARE @Doctable TABLE (id bigint identity(1,1), ekey  nvarchar(250) , esize int, [econtents] varbinary(max) )

INSERT INTO @Doctable([ekey] , [esize],[econtents])
Select top 5 ekey, esize, econtents from eattachment
select * from @doctable

SELECT @i = COUNT(1) FROM @Doctable

WHILE @i <= 5
BEGIN 

    SET @ekey = (SELECT STUFF(LEFT(ekey,33),1,1,'') from @doctable where id = @i)
    SET @efoldername =  (select top 1 efoldername
                                    from efolder 
                                    where efolderid 
                                    like @ekey
                                    )
    SET @outPutPath = '\\location\to\store\files'

    SELECT --fails here
     @econtents = [econtents],
     @fPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ [id] + '\' + @efolderName + '\' + RIGHT(ekey, LEN(ekey) - 33), 
     @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ [id]
    FROM @Doctable WHERE id = @i

  EXEC  [dbo].[CreateFolder]  @folderPath
  EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; 
  EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;  
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @econtents; 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2; 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; 
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; 

  print 'Document saved to: '+  @fPath   

SELECT @econtents = NULL  
, @init = NULL
, @fPath = NULL  
, @folderPath = NULL
SET @i = 1
END
```

Why is it failing with that error? I would expect it to just copy the files to my folder.

I can't see any varchar->bigint conversions happening, especially on the line it says its failed on.

I suspect it's something to do with the `econtents` column being of type `image` in the source table and `varbinary` in the temporary table. SQL told me I wasn't allowed to use `image` in procedures/declaring variables, so I thought it would convert automatically?

Edit: This is not anything to do with the other post as that's a datetime conversion issue. Someone already posted an answer which worked, but they have deleted it

Comment: Just for reference: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Comment: The issue is a matter of data type precedence, as shown in the duplicate. The data type of `[id]` is `BigInt`. When it is used in an expression along with string types it causes the strings to be converted to `BigInt` as explained in the documentation for [data type precendence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). Since some of the other expressions being concatenated into `@fpath` don't contain valid numeric data you are rewarded with "Error converting data type varchar to bigint." Convert `[id]` to a string: `Cast( [id] as VarChar(16) )`.

Comment: Fine. Fixed it anyway

Comment: I still think it's a duplicate, but since someone (or someones) reopened it, I've undeleted my answer. Please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've marked yours as the answer. It fixed this problem. I do have another issue though which I posted on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
 @fPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ [id] + '\' + @efolderName + '\' + RIGHT(ekey, LEN(ekey) - 33), 
 @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ [id]
```

When concatenating strings to bigint, SQL Server will try to implicitly convert the string to bigint and sum instead of concat, unless you explicitly convert the bigint to a string data type.

change it to

```
 @fPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ CAST([id] as varchar(21)) + '\' + @efolderName + '\' + RIGHT(ekey, LEN(ekey) - 33), 
 @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ CAST([id] as varchar(21))
```

(you need 21 chars since min value of bigint has 20 digits and a minus sign).

Comment: Just for reference: [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql).

Comment: @Habo Please post your comment on the question, as I want to delete my answer since it's a duplicat.